# Convert UPDATE with INNER JOIN from SQL for use in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like to convert this for us in MySQL:

```
UPDATE product 
SET price = 12.95 
FROM product 
    INNER JOIN product_to_category ON product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id 
    INNER JOIN category ON product_to_category.category_id = category.category_id 
        AND category.parent_id = 39
```

MySQL doesn't like the FROM portion, and I'm not sure that the INNER JOINs will work as written either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE product 
SET price = 12.95 
WHERE product_id in
(SELECT product_id 
FROM product_to_category 
INNER JOIN category 
ON product_to_category.category_id = category.category_id 
WHERE category.parent_id = 39)
```

Comment: MySQL still doesn't like the 'FROM product' line

Comment: @Deca: There is no `FROM PRODUCT` in the provided query.

Comment: Bah, you're right - sorry about that. Pasted the wrong clipboard into my SQL box. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your database, so I can't really test, but I suppose you could use the [multi-table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) for your update statement :

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Quoting the manual :

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE
>   updates rows in each table named in
>   table_references that satisfy the
>   conditions.

In your case, something like this might do the trick :

```
UPDATE product, product_to_category, category
SET product.price = 12.95 
WHERE product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id 
    AND product_to_category.category_id = category.category_id 
    AND category.parent_id = 39
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I actually only need to update one table - product - but based on criteria from the other two tables. I'll try a variant of this one, looks like it's in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The general syntax for a multiple-table UPDATE statement is

```
UPDATE <table>
    (INNER|LEFT|RIGHT|...) JOIN <table2> ON <condition> 
SET <field>=<value>
WHERE <condition>
```

So your statement should work if you rewrite it to

```
UPDATE product 
    INNER JOIN product_to_category ON product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id
    INNER JOIN category ON product_to_category.category_id = category.category_id AND category.parent_id = 39
SET price = 12.95
```

(untested, I don't have a mysql instance at hand)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE product 
    INNER JOIN product_to_category ON product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id 
    INNER JOIN category ON product_to_category.category_id = category.category_id 
        AND category.parent_id = 39
SET product.price = 12.95
```