# Update statement from a join

Tags: mysql

I have this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `all_uu_features`

INNER JOIN `all_video_names`
ON `all_video_names`.`video_id` = `all_uu_features`.`video_id`

WHERE `language` = 'en'
  AND `navigation` = 'laser-interface'
```

I need to reverse this and UPDATE the database.  How do I do that?  Is there a better way than:

```
UPDATE `all_uu_features` SET ...
WHERE `language` = 'en'
  AND `navigation` = 'laser-interface'
```

and

```
UPDATE `all_video_names' SET ...
WHERE video_id = ?
```

Can this be done with one statement?

all_video_names:

```
video_id | video_name
-------------------
1        |  ABC
2        |  DEF
3   ....
```

all_uu_features:

```
feature_name | video_id |  language | navigation
-----------------------------------------------
Hello 1      |  1       |   en      | laser-interface
Hello 2      |  2       |   fr      | laser-interface
```

Comment: It's not immediately apparent what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting.  I need to update the two tables from data in a CMS.  How do I combine both statements with a join?

Comment: What columns do you need to update?  What tables are they from?  What is the schema of each table?

Comment: I need to update feature_name and video_name

Comment: Why can't you use two statements wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: I found another example on here that used a join but it's a different schema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849726/convert-update-with-inner-join-from-sql-for-use-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a multi-table update syntax in MySQL. You can actually find an example in the docs of almost exactly what you're trying to do.

```
-- docs example
UPDATE TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.COLUMN_1= TABLE_2.COLUMN_2 
SET TABLE_1.COLUMN = EXPR WHERE TABLE_2.COLUMN2 IS NULL
```

In your case, it would be:

```
UPDATE
`all_uu_features` uu    
INNER JOIN `all_video_names` vid
ON uu.`video_id` = vid.`video_id`
SET uu.column_name = 1, vid.column_name = 2
WHERE `language` = 'en'
  AND `navigation` = 'laser-interface';
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thanks, cwallenpoole.

Comment: I don't understand when I use a left join or a right join or an inner join?  Is there somewhere I can read up on something a little less dense than MySQL's website?

Comment: Found this, which is clearer than MySQL's site.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL