# Update with Where clause

Tags: mysql

I have run this below query and it is giving error:

```
UPDATE t_o
SET t_o.mlm_order_id = mt.order_id 
FROM temp_orders t_o, mlm_transaction mt
WHERE mt.v2_order_id = t_o.order_id
```

Error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'FROM temp_orders t_o, mlm_transaction mt WHERE mt.v2_order_id = t_o.order_id' 
at line 3
```

Please help ??

Comment: UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value          correct syntax. try again.

Comment: In stack overflow:
[take Look here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849726/convert-update-with-inner-join-from-sql-for-use-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

the one you are using is a syntax of `SQLServer`. This is the equivalent for `MySQL`

```
UPDATE temp_orders t_o 
       INNER JOIN mlm_transaction mt
            ON mt.v2_order_id = t_o.order_id
SET    t_o.mlm_order_id = mt.order_id
```

Comment: This query is running but giving this error after some time: #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: How to handle this error: #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: did you specify keys on these columns: `mt.v2_order_id`, `t_o.order_id`? primary key or foreign key? or even index them?

Comment: NO I have not defined any primary key or foreign key on mt.v2_order_id, t_o.order_id and also not index them.

Comment: The query is OK, I mean syntax is correct. The error connected with locked tables/rows. Try to find out transaction that uses these tables, and commit it firstly.

Comment: @FaizanRana because the query requires full table scan. modify your table by adding index on `mt.v2_order_id`, `t_o.order_id`

Answer (score 1):

One more version -

```
UPDATE temp_orders t_o, mlm_transaction mt
SET t_o.mlm_order_id = mt.order_id 
WHERE mt.v2_order_id = t_o.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, untested though:

```
UPDATE t_o
SET t_o.mlm_order_id = mt.order_id 
WHERE t_o.mlm_order_id = (SELECT mt.v2_order_id FROM mlm_transaction mt WHERE mt.v2_order_id = t_o.order_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updates don't use the FROM clause.

Use something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1, column2=value2,... WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You can comment on the question. Or you can add solution as an answer.

Comment: I believe that what's most important is to know that updates don't use the "FROM" clause, which was the problem with the original statement.